# Change image in viewholder image on click

Tags: android, listview, view, onclick, adapter

The image changes as it should when the button is click,but I'm running into a probably where as new items are added,the old imageview gets reverted while the newer onces that weren't click get changed.

```
holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_fave_on_default);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes indeed. That happens because these views are recycled.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to fix this kind of issue? I'm build a twitter app and each listitem has a favorite button,this is a big issue.

Comment: Take the time to read this forum. There are so many posts where the same problem is described. But you need a code a good adapter with a getView method and a holder.